# systemc inout port binding issue

Tags: systemc

I am a beginner to systemC.

I have a module which has a port defined as

```
sc_inout<sc_lv<8> > data;
```

and I am trying to drive it in the test bench as

```
sc_signal_rv<8> data;
...
module.data(data);
data =  0;
...
```

but the signal is  always x. I checked all other signals which are only either in port or  out port,  they all give correct values. Please help  me to clear the issue. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not possible to tell from your code snippet where is your error. In case you drive sc_signal_rv from multiple processes, it will have x value.

Comment: problem solved.  Do not use sc_signal_rv since it does not accept sc_lv type but only a int int, like 8.  I used sc_signal_rv<8> is  a mismatch of data type with the inout port firstly. Just change to sc_signal<sc_lv<8> > data. I don't know why because i was told that sc_signal_rv is for multiple drivers, which  i think the inout case would be exactly  what it should be used for.